# Rate of convergence for ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I want to show that the experimental rate of convergence (EOC) for ordinary differential equations is

$$EOC(h):= \frac {\log\left(\frac{e_h(t)}{e_{h/2}(t)}\right)}{\log(2)}$$

with $e_h(t)$ being the difference between the actual solution and the numerical solution in $t$ with an increment of $h$.

My idea was to rearrange this formula. One will get:

$$\frac{e_h(t)}{e_{h/2}(t)}=2^p$$

So basically, I can show this instead of the above.

Since $e_h(t)=Ch^p + o(h^p)$ for $C>0$ and $h \rightarrow 0$, we have:

$$\frac{e_h(t)}{e_{h/2}(t)}=\frac{Ch^p + o(h^p)}{C({h/2})^p + o(({h/2})^p)}$$

But how does the last one equal $2^p$? I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Yes, cancel $C(h/2)^p$ in that fraction to get $2^p+o_h(1)$.

Comment: @LutzL so $\frac{Ch^p}{C(h/2)^p}=2^p$ and $\frac{C(h/2)^p}{C(h/2)^p}=1$ but what exactly are:
$\frac{o(h^p)}{C(h/2)^p}$ and $\frac{o((h/2)^p)}{C(h/2)^p}$? How do you write that down to get to your solution?

Comment: The latter two are quantities that converge to $0$ for $h\to 0$, denoted as $o(h^0)$ or $o(1)$. As $\frac1{1+o(1)}=1+o(1)$ one can reduce the denominator.